# Css3 calc minus vh with pixel

Tags: css, sass, less

```
.wrap {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

this won't work. I got output of 50vh. Is there any where I can minus pixel with vh?

Comment: Working fine for me on Chrome/Win https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/qozoe4d6/

Comment: Which browser you are using? Check for `calc()` browser support.

Comment: Not actually the case here, but in case someone has problems with this as I did: calc requires spaces left and right of the + and - operator.

Comment: @MichaelVillani O! MY! GOD! Tnx man, you save my day

Answer (score 64):

Less:

```
.wrap {
    height: calc(~"100vh - 50px");
}
```

Sass or pure css:

```
.wrap {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

Comment: What's the point in posting a duplicate answer despite my comment being there already? I know you've included a Sass version but OP has indicated an *error* which only happens if you write it that way with Less. Also, your Sass/pure CSS version is already there in the question itself.

Comment: It was actually very helpful for me and I'm so glad he posted it.

Comment: Thanks for posting it as the answer. Comments are discussions and might not help all the time. @Harry, this is helping the community, your comment isn't!

Comment: > calc requires spaces left and right of the + and - operator.